# How do you take out the Hammer Brothers in Super Mario Bros.?

Tags: super-mario-bros

They always kill me or make me little and I have literally not found a way to kill them. The ones that are on the blocks like in this picture aren't as bad because you can hit the blocks to take them out. The problem are the ones that are just standing there say, on a set of stairs or something.

Is there some trick to this that I am just not getting?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The trick is **all in the timing**. It's a lot harder to time your way through two sets of hammers (ala in the above case), but once you're underneath the bros, taking them out becomes trivial - as you can just hit the block they're standing on.

The ones on the ground are still a matter of timing. **Wait for the long pause** between throws (happens once every 4 or 5 hammers) and run through the hammer arc. Stay between the hammer bro and his arc until the next pause (this may require moving a little with the hammer bro), and just when the next pause appears, take your chance and jump on his head. If timed correctly, he'll miss you with his last hammer, but not even get a chance to throw his next one.

As with all things, **practice makes perfect**. The more you tango with these creatures, the better you get at timing their throws and consistently avoiding those deadly hammers.

Comment: Here is [a TAS example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4YHWOV5s6HI#t=235s) showing how they all get killed, between two hammers must be tricky...

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped for a while in 8-4 of super mario bros game and watch... I got to close to the end and then the hammer bro killed me every time. However, finally figure out how to defeat it. Wait for it to jump and then jump at the same time, when it reaches the ground jump on its head! If you wait until after it has jumped it will recommence throwing hammers at you ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Just jump on their heads without getting hit by a hammer.  It takes good timing and practice, and in practice I've found the run-in-fast-an-jump method shown in Pubby8's answer doesn't work because they don't always jump or throw the hammer the samway.

Answer (score -1):

If you jump over the hammer bro from a safe distance (a few blocks), you will be able to jump over the hammer bro, and no hammer bro for you